# HTTP 404 The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I was following the tutorial on:
https://www.javahelps.com/2015/04/java-web-application-hello-world.html

The Tomcat server is running well on:
http://localhost:8080/

This page is displayed correctly:
http://localhost:8080/Hello_World/

However, when I press "Click here" and go to this link:
http://localhost:8080/Hello_World/saytime
The above error is displayed.
Here is my code:

```
package help;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

  /**
  * Servlet implementation class HelloWorldServlet
  */
 @WebServlet("/saytime")
 public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public HelloWorldServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("<html><body><h1 align='center'>" +
    new Date().toString() + "</h1></body></html>");
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

  }`
```

I noticed that I don't have web.xml file

Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance,

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="saytime">Click Here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us your HTML code

Comment: @Gopi Here you go

Comment: I tried as mentioned in the tutorial and I don't see any issue with the link. Can you show the structure of your project including project title, packages, classes , files.

Comment: I followed that tutorial and it worked for me. I notice that you are not using the package name in the tutorial (`help` vs. `com.javahelps.helloworld`), your code is poorly formatted, and there is an invalid character at the end of your Java source. Completely discard what you have done and repeat the tutorial (it only takes 2 minutes), but follow the instructions in that tutorial _exactly_ rather than selectively. Also, check your code build for any warnings/errors before running it.